# Why is it important to transform the data into normal / Gaussian distribution when creating a linear regression model

Tags: linear-regression

I'm currently building my first regression model, and as we know that, owing to the limitations of the algorithm, we need to remove outliers and transform the distribution into a normal one.

I know that it's important and the ways to do it, but can someone please help me in understanding why exactly we need to do so? Why can't I work with a highly skewed distribution? Why does linear regression mandates this transformation in processing stage?

Answer (score 0):

[Classifier with and without Outliers in the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yg5d.png)

Hope the above picture clears your doubt.

As LinearRegression model is optimized by passing through a path which has minimum squared error,
due to outliers (which are abnormal data points or noise) our classifier may deviate and work poorly on the test data (much general data).